# Keep refreshing until two strings are equal

Tags: php

I'm busy on a site for a game, I'm building a verification system, when a user registeres on my site, a PHP function generates a code, and when they want to access any page, they'll be redirected to the `activateplayer.php` page, where their code will be displayed.

Then, as verification they put that code in their name. If the code is the same, they can push the button, and their player is verified. The whole script works, but when they adjust their name to the corresponding code, they need to refresh the page to see the button.

Is there a way to keey 'refreshing' the function that gets their IGN (InGame Name), or the part that checks if they're equal. I'll also post some code:

The page that checks if the player isn't verified already and checks the equality of the codes:

```
<?php
$query = $db->conn->prepare('SELECT habactive FROM ht_users WHERE naam = ? AND habactive = "0"');
$query->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['user']['username']);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($active);
$query->store_result();
if ($query->num_rows > 0 )
{
    while($query->fetch()) 
    {
?>
        Whoops! Het ziet er naar uit dat jouw speler nog niet geverifieerd is. Dit moet omdat anderen misschien accounts gaan aanmaken op jouw naam.<br>Om je speler te verifieren moet je de onderstaande code in je status zetten. Als je speler geverifieerd is kun je die code er weer uit halen, en vallen wij je niet meer lastig!<br><br>
        Jouw persoonlijke code is:<br><b><?php echo ($_SESSION['user']['code_activation']); ?></b><br><br>Jouw huidige IGN is:<br><b><div id="motto">
        <?php 
        echo $functions->getIGN($_SESSION['user']['username']);
        if($_SESSION['user']['code_activation'] === $functions->getIGN($_SESSION['user']['username']))
        {
            ?>
                <form action="activeerspeler.php" method="post">
                <table align="center" cellpadding="8" style="100%">
                <td width="30%">
                    <input type="submit" name="verifieer" value="Verifieer mijn speler!" class="button small orange" style="width: 100%;">
                </td>
                </table>
                </form>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
    else
{
    ?>

        Whoops! Jouw speler is al geverifieerd. Klik <a href="index.php">hier om naar de homepagina te gaan. </a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Code examples should be in English on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT the best method... however...

```
if($_SESSION['user']['code_activation'] === $functions->getIGN($_SESSION['user']['username'])){

$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
}
```

I think should do what you want but...
I would really recommend an AJAX solution based on JavaScript onkeyup trigger on the field that they are going to change